# Which does static library have `__imp_ExtractIconA ` symbols?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, static-libraries

I want to know which does static library have  `__imp_ExtractIconA`  symbols? Tell me if you know, please.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: [The `ExtractIconA` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-extracticona) might tell you.

Comment: Please review ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). The question is missing context and tags, and doesn't tell us what you have done to try to answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

It's not in a static library, it's in a dynamic library, [`Shell32.DLL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-extracticona)

Comment: thank you for answer.  I used `#pragma comment(lib, "shell32.lib")` in my code and It's successful.

Comment: @RobertDu: `shell32.lib` is the _import_ library for `shell32.dll`, and itself doesn't contain the function.